# Number of 10-digit integers that have at least 3 different digits

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

I want to know how many 10-digit integers have at least 3 different digits, if leading 0 is not allowed.

Ideally this question would help me learn the inclusion-exclusion principle. So I started with all the possible 10-digit integers, then tried to subtract those 10-digit numbers with the same digit, and also subtract those 10-digit numbers that have only 2 distinct digits.

$ (9 * 10^9) - 9 - (9 * \binom{9}{1} 1^9) $

But I am not sure about my representation of the third term, or if there is any overlap between the sets of "only 1 distinct" and "only 2 distinct" that would make it necessary to add something back.

Comment: Find the number of 10- digit integers having only 1 or 2 different digits. Subtract this number from the number of 10-digit integers.

Comment: Is my estimate for the 10-digit integers that have only 2 different digits correct?

Comment: $9*$$9\choose 1$$*(2^9 -1)$ is the no of 10-digit integers that have only 2 different digits

Comment: Oh, I see now that I did not allow for alternation between the two digits. Why did you subtract 1 from $2^9$ though?

Comment: The digit in the first place may appear in each of the remaining 9 places, but that would defeat the purpose, as the integer must contain exactly two distinct digits

Answer (score 1):

There are $9$ options for the first digit. Then there are $10^9$ options for the remaining digits, of which $1$ consists only of the first digit and $\binom91(2^9-1)$ contain exactly one other digit, so the total is

$$
9\left(10^9-1-9\left(2^9-1\right)\right)=8999958600\;.
$$